# Recycler View has lag when add Bitmap to it

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I Have a recycler view that shows multi bitmap from the SQLite database. When the number of bitmaps increases, recycler view scrolled with lag, In addition, The whole program slows down.

I save bitmap from a view to a database like this (convert bitmap to byte):

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getWidth(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
view.draw(canvas);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
DatabaseHelper.updateData(id, stream.toByteArray());
```

And convert the byte to a bitmap in onBindViewHolder adapter like this:

```
byte[] byte = items.get(position).getImageByte();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byte, 0, byte.length);
holder.ivShot.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

And this is my fragment that initializing recycler view:

```
ModelArrayList = DatabaseHelper.getData();
Adapter = new Adapter(ModelArrayList, DatabaseHelper);
recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
recycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 2));
recycler.setAdapter(Adapter);
```

How I can fix this error?

Comment: Why would you want to save bitmap to local database?

Comment: @HasanBouTaam To show this page in another Activity!

Comment: I mean its a bad practice, as bitmaps tend to be large, this why it begins to lag.

Comment: instead do as I told you below.

Comment: @HasanBouTaam I want to show a preview of the web view in the tabs screen.

Comment: What tabs screen, and why you need webview?

Comment: @HasanBouTaam I try to make a small web browser with webview.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211948/discussion-between-marlen-schreiner-and-hasan-bou-taam).

Comment: @MarlenSchreiner What did you finally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you can reduce the size of the bitmap for better performance, But I tested it with the Glide library and the lag issue was solved.

```
Glide.with(context).load("your byte")
            .placeholder("default image")
            .into(viewHolder.imageView);
```

Comment: Doesn't using this library cause memory leaks?

Comment: @MarlenSchreiner I think this library can manage resources and cache, so don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Bitmap loading is a very sensitive and complicated topic, as bitmap size gets larger you will face more memory issues, and hence the lag.

Your best way to load bitmaps in recyclerview is to keep your bitmaps in Files and load them using some well known efficient libraries like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I had a question: When you click **tabs** on **google chrome** app, You see a preview of the site. Isn't this a bitmap preview? Why doesn't the speed of the program change with increasing tabs?

Comment: @MarlenSchreiner it depends on the size of the bitmap, and the way they load them efficiently, as I told you its a very advanced concept and very hard to get loading bitmaps efficient by yourself, thats why libraries like Glide exist.

Comment: I need to program a page in my program that looks like a browser tab. So you tell me I save bitmap in Files and load them next? Give me some advice to use smaller bitmap And there is no need to save bitmaps in files. I'm sorry I took your time.

Comment: if the app is offline I suggest put in files and load with some library, if the app is online then put the files on some server like firebase storage and also load the url with glide or other library.

Comment: Oh, This takes a lot of time. I should show a preview at the moment. Is there a way to reduce the size of the bitmap? like use **thumbnail**?

Comment: @MarlenSchreiner try and see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a less memory-hungry version of the image called `thumbnail`.
Then pass the thumbnail to the `Recycler-View`. Android has an API for this

```
import android.media.ThumbnailUtils

Bitmap thumbnailBitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(originalBitmap, width, height);
```

Make sure to get rid of the original Bitmap afterwards.

```
originalBitmap.recycle();
```